# How to take the middle out of a highchart donut chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am modifying this donut chart and need to remove the middle and replace it with a text:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/

What is the best way to do that?

```
$(function () {

    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
        name = 'Browser brands',
        data = [{
                y: 55.11,
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'MSIE versions',
                    categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                    data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
            }, {
                y: 21.63,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                    data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                    color: colors[1]
                }
            }, {
                y: 11.94,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Chrome versions',
                    categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                        'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                    data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                    color: colors[2]
                }
            }, {
                y: 7.15,
                color: colors[3],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Safari versions',
                    categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                        'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                    data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                    color: colors[3]
                }
            }, {
                y: 2.14,
                color: colors[4],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Opera versions',
                    categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                    data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                    color: colors[4]
                }
            }];


    // Build the data arrays
    var browserData = [];
    var versionsData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        // add browser data
        browserData.push({
            name: categories[i],
            y: data[i].y,
            color: data[i].color
        });

        // add version data
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].drilldown.data.length; j++) {
            var brightness = 0.2 - (j / data[i].drilldown.data.length) / 5 ;
            versionsData.push({
                name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
                color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
            });
        }
    }

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false,
                center: ['50%', '50%']
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: browserData,
            size: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: 'white',
                distance: -30
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Versions',
            data: versionsData,
            size: '80%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    // display only if larger than 1
                    return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get empty space in the middle of a chart use 'size' and 'innerSize' - Like in your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/pPCNg/1/):

```
            size: '80%',
            innerSize: '60%'
```

Regarding text - I advice to use [renderer.text()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text%28%29).